# Setting UITableViewCell subtitiles values equal to system date and time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am pretty new in objective c.Here I am using story board project from this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) .There i add subtitle on storyboard.How i can pick the system date and time at time of cell creation and display it as value of subtitles cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSDate date]` will return system date (simulator, device) when cell is created. See below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the current time by calling

```
[NSDate date];
```

You can then format this into a string using **NSDateFormatter** e.g.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Be aware that NSDateFormatter is an expensive class to instantiate so you should prepare it ahead of use.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];`

will print system date and time.if you want to change the format use `NSDateFormatter`